# Add another element inside created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document.createElement('div'))
.attr({
    'class':'sniper-alert'
})
.html(words)
.css({
    'position':'fixed',
    'width':'30%',
    'height':'30%',
    'box-shadow':'0 1px 3px #888',
    'top':'30%',
    'left':'50%',
    'transform':'translate(-50%, -50%)'
})
.fadeIn()
.prependTo('body');
```

hi, I have got a problem here.  I just want to ask how to create another element inside my `div`.  I want to add button on it.  I'm making my own alert-type-box.  a big thanks for those who want to help

Comment: You can use `.append()` on the jQuery object you initially created or you can add the button HTML to the `words` string before you do `.html()`.

Comment: this words is the text which would i input later like for example `myalert('ok')` the words is the container of _'ok_'. what i want is to create a button there where i can also add attributes in it.btw, thanks

Comment: Depends on whether the button should come before or after the "words".

Comment: Could you show the HTML you're trying to create? With the relevant content, so we can see where in the `<div>` the `<button>` should be? And what text should be in the created-`<div>` and the created-`<button>`?

Comment: i dont want to use an html. the code is a function. which i cn call at a later time for multi-purpose use.btw, thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways: `element.appendChild(node)` and `element.innerHTML = "html-as-string"`.  Both of these have jQuery equivalents, but the plain javascript seems just as easy/supported to me.

For a button, your script might be something like

```
var elem = $("div-id"); // the code in the question has no id, but you'll need some way to select the div
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.innerHTML = "Click Me!";
elem.appendChild(button);
```

This is untested and may have typos. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add the new `<div>` to the document you can append another element; in this example it will be put right after the text contents:

```js
$('<div>', {
  class: 'sniper-alert',
  html: 'words',
  css: {
    'position':'fixed',
    'width':'30%',
    'height':'30%',
    'box-shadow':'0 1px 3px #888',
    'top':'30%',
    'left':'50%',
    'transform':'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  }
})
.append('<button>button</button>')
.fadeIn()
.prependTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can append anything you like, including another jQuery object.

Comment: so there's no way to use another `createElement` code?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @sagay_paul You're welcome; please remember to accept the answer that best helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery function "append()" this will append at the end of your div selector Like that way :

```
$("#div_id").append("<input type='button' id='clickbtn' name='Click' value='Click
> Button'>");
```

if you would like to perform click event on that button then you need to bind the click event like this :

```
$("#clickbtn").on('click',function(){
// Your Code
});
```